# Benefitting from recent performance improvements in git/scalar despite submodules and Git LFS?

Tags: git

I investigated the utility -- performance-wise -- of [`scalar`](https://git-scm.com/docs/scalar) (in upstream Git since 2.38) for our work with Git repositories.

We have plenty of use-cases were the performance improvements would make a big difference, *especially for the CI*.

However, both with the traditional `git` CLI as well as with `scalar` our use of submodules (more than one level deep, unfortunately) and Git LFS seems to be the proverbial brick wall for many use cases:

1. our use of submodules:`scalar` has no switch corresponding to `--recurse-submodules` for the `clone` operation ... hence in order to do anything we have to initialize the submodules "manually" after the cloning etc
2. Git LFS: Turns out that cloning with `scalar` is *also* very fast because it simply skips the LFS filtering step (despite LFS filtering being activated in the global Git configuration)

**Question:** Are there ways to get around these limitations to bend `scalar` to our needs? Or is `scalar` only catering the needs of those with huge monorepos without Git LFS and submodules?

In case it matters, we are working with Git both on Linux *and* Windows.